# How to use Spring Cloud Config Client in Spring Boot applications deployed to non-embedded tomcats?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I’d like to use Spring Cloud Config Client in a Spring Boot Application deployed to a non-embedded tomcat
as [spring-boot-traditional](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-traditional). It, however, cannot connect to a Spring-cloud-config-server. The main confiugration class is as follows,

```
@ImportResource({"classpath:/META-INF/spring/spring-security.xml",
    "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml"})
@EnableRedisHttpSession
@EnableCaching
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    JmxAutoConfiguration.class, SessionAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {

}
```

As [the traditional sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-traditional), it does’t extends `SpringBootServletInitializer`.
When it extended the initializer, it could connect to a Spring cloud-config server, but other features, including CSRF token check and Redis session didn’t work well.

Thank you.

Comment: When deploying you must extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` else your application will not deploy. It should behave (more or less) the same when deploying or launching. If it doesn't you are doing things wrong (you don't have an accidental `web.xml` do you?)

Comment: Thank you for the information